# What's the easiest way to move tile-based services?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-9.3, tiles

We're still running ArcGIS 9.3.1 for a short while longer, and have been tiling more of our data, which is great until we have to deploy it. Deploying currently consists of transferring the entirety of the tileset to the production machines, which takes about half of forever, especially on a deadline. We're currently using tar.gz, but would welcome a better approach. Tiling in place is not an option as there is not a "spare" server at the production facility.

Edit:
I should mention that the destination server is a *long* way away, and behind a firewall, meaning that our access to it is limited, and mapping a drive or a share is Right Out. I'd be tempted to use external drives and FedEx, but that would require a physical person at the destination, which tends not to be the case for months at a time.

Comment: Love to see an answer to this. We've got one service (for example) that has over 3M files (613MB, 11.5GB on disk); it just takes a _long_ time to copy that many files.

Comment: It's crazy to not make an archive, but zip won't usually deal with that many files. Tar is pretty standard, but I was seriously hoping for a better solution. OTOH, we're migrating to 10, which makes a *lot* fewer files for a tileset.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe try [RichCopy](http://download.microsoft.com/download/f/d/0/fd05def7-68a1-4f71-8546-25c359cc0842/HoffmanUtilitySpotlight2009_04.exe)?  I haven't moved tile caches with it, but I've used it with a few big file geodatabases.  You can set the thread count and specify various checks for the copy.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/2009.04.utilityspotlight.aspx
[image]

Comment: Also, you can use command line arguments. You can also use the GUI initially to create the command line args and copy/paste them to your batch file.

Answer (score 1):

How about [xcopy](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisserver/9.3.1/dotNet/index.htm#copying_caches.htm)?

Comment: That's also extremely slow. From experience.

Comment: and use it with a .bat file with task scheduler for overnight (out of office time) for optimum speed in transfer across WAN/LAN etc.

Comment: or "robocopy" if you've got it.

Answer (score 1):

[jzip](http://www.jzip.com/) and ftp ([filezilla](http://filezilla-project.org/client_features.php))

Comment: Never heard of jzip...how's it compare to 7zip?

Comment: How is it different from other compression utilities?
jZip is built on proven and reliable 7-Zip technology. 7-Zip technology is fast and achieves compression ratios that are higher or equivalent to other leading compression programs. jZip differs from applications like WinZip when it comes to cost. jZip is FREE and we plan to keep it free for both home and enterprise users. We believe that the ability to create and open archive files should be free and available to all.

Comment: so it is 7zip but seems more user friendly.